# How to save image in access database using WPF vb.net Codes

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to save image from folder to access database. Here is My code in Saving.

```
    Dim FileDialog As New OpenFileDialog
    Try
        Dim sqlconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim sqlquery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim connString As String

        Dim Stream As FileStream
        Dim Reader As StreamReader
        Stream = New FileStream(tbpath.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Reader = New StreamReader(Stream)
        Dim ImagePath(Stream.Length - 1) As Byte
        Stream.Read(ImagePath, 0, Stream.Length - 1)
        connString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= \\10.227.31.22\CPS$\Computer Profile System.mdb"
        sqlconn.ConnectionString = connString
        sqlquery.Connection = sqlconn
        sqlconn.Open()
        sqlquery.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TempLog(PIC, ControlNumber, Department, DateDelivered, Warranty,ImagePath)VALUES(@pic, @controlnumber, @department, @datedelivered, @warranty, @ImagePath)"
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pic", tbname.Text)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@controlnumber", tbcontrol.Text)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", tbdepartment.Text)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datedelivered", tbdatedelivered.Text)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@warranty", tbwarranty.Text)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePath", ImagePath)
        sqlquery.ExecuteNonQuery()

        lblpath.Content = FileDialog.FileName(tbpath.Text.Trim) & " Stored Successfully...."


        If tbname.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("PLEASE ENTER NAME.")
        ElseIf tbcontrol.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("PLEASE ENTER CONTROL NUMBER.")
        ElseIf tbname.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("PLEASE ENTER NAME.")
        ElseIf tbcontrol.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("PLEASE ENTER CONTROL NUMBER.")
        ElseIf tbname.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("PLEASE ENTER NAME.")
        ElseIf tbcontrol.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("PLEASE ENTER CONTROL NUMBER.")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("RECORD SUCCESSFULLY.")
        End If
        sqlquery.ExecuteNonQuery()

        sqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function FileName(ByVal Pth As String) As String
    Dim SlashPosition As Integer = Pth.LastIndexOf("\")
    Dim Flname As String = Pth.Substring(SlashPosition + 1)
    Return Flname
End Function
```

The error says "Conversion from string "Path of Image" to type 'integer' is not valid". Please Help. I've been stuck here for a week.

Comment: This has nothing to do with WPF. Either you store the image file path as string, or you get the file content by `File.ReadAllBytes` and store that as a blob.

Comment: Can you please help me with this? just modify my code? please help